# Sending Excel VBA email

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code in excel VBA. I need to send it by email. It looks fine but the email is not received. Can someone help me?

```
i = 4
Do While Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 11).Value = "Pabaigtas" And Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 12).Value = "NE" And Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value <> "DONE" Then
        Sheets("Email").Range("A2:P2").ClearContents
        Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 16)).Copy
        Sheets("Email").Range("A2:P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = "DONE"
        Sheets("Email").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P2").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
           .Introduction = "NEATITIKIMU REGISTRAS"
           .Item.To = "justas.sirvinskas@havi.com" & ";" & "artur.poplavski@havi.com" & ";" & "vladimir.volchonskij@havi.com" & ";" & "anzelika.tamkun@havi.com" & ";" & "inga.maleckiene@havi.com" & ";" & "jurate.balzere@havi.com" & ";" & "andrius.kubilius@havi.com" & ";" & "rolandas.smaliukas@havi.com" & ";" & "jolanta.biciukiene@havi.com" & ";" & "edvinas.gerika@havi.com"
           .Item.Subject = "PABAIGTA UZDUOTIS NEATITIKIMU REGISTRE"
           .Item.Send
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Is ms Outlook your standard email client? What are the versions of your Excel and your Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too and I used this code below to send using outlook:

```
Public Sub testOutlook()
    Dim OutApp  As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    OutMail.Display
    Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
    strbody = "Some text here"

    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "TEST"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & Signature
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```